# how to run GcmListenerService in foreground

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, foreground-service

I have a problem sometimes with my GCM service which is closed when RAM of my smartphone is automatically cleared (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612007/gcm-service-is-deleted-with-cache-clearing) if you need more details).

As far as I understand if I set my service to run in foreground it should help the system to to delete it with RAM. The method of `Service.class` `onStartCommand()` is usually used to run `startForeground()` method.

But with the latest version of GCM implementation it is impossible since the `onStartCommand()` method of the parent `GCMListenerService.class` is defined as **final** and I cannot override it.

So how can I set my gcm receiver to rum in foreground?

Here is my manifest part about GCM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.app.path" >    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <!-- ... other permissions -->

<permission
    android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    ...>
     <!-- ... activites... -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="my.app.path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListener"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31302248/4186942). Or one possible solution is `sendOrderedBroadcast`. For more details of this please refer [here](http://markhudnall.com/2013/11/13/gcm-foreground-and-background/): http://markhudnall.com/2013/11/13/gcm-foreground-and-background/.

Comment: How much RAM are you targeting?

Comment: @ArthurThompson, do you mean how much RAM my phone has? The current version of the app is 3.55Mb

Comment: Yes how much RAM does the phone have?

Comment: 3Gb(!!!) with Android 5, it is a xiaomi smartphone

Comment: I posted an answer to [your related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612007/gcm-service-is-deleted-with-cache-clearing).  If your instance of `GcmListenerService` gets destroyed by the system to reclaim memory, I don't know why it would not be recreated by `GcmReceiver` when the next message is received.  There is no need to run `GcmListenerService` in the foreground to protect it from being destroyed.

Comment: It's a little bit strange answer: you're describing what should happen, but it does not happen. As you can see in my case MyListenerService is not started in few hours again, that's why I want to test how foreground works.

Comment: How about adding `serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);` to your service intent in the `onMessageReceived()` method and making the required notification to show the user the service is still running with `startForeground(1, notification);`

Comment: @Slartibartfast: the problem is that the method onMessageReceived() is not called because the relevant class (service) is deleted from memory.

Comment: Have you checked the phone's log?

Comment: Oh, and how are you getting feedback that you have received a message anyway?

Comment: @DavidSainty, I don't get any message anyway, since either Listener or Receiver is obviously deleted by process manager MIUI. 
When I do receive a message a see a standard android notification

Comment: It isn't meant to be necessary for the GcmListenerService to be running.  Receivers and services (and Activities) are instantiated on demand.  Putting the service in the foreground isn't a good solution, and doesn't stop the service from being at least occasionally not running.

Comment: I don't know how to prevent my app not to stop receivenig messages when the RAM of my smartphone is rather full and it starts to clean all the processes

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.  The service should be able to be shut down, and should be revived on the next message.  How certain are you that the service doesn't get restarted?  Have you tried adding debug logging?

Comment: @DavidSainty, my problem exists. I'm pretty sure that device is not restaterted, I'm not an idiot. No, the service just disapperas. You can read about it somewhere else, if you want, many people do write about such properties of MIUI, it's some kind of bug of the system. The problem is that more and more people in the world buy smartphones based on MIUI and I was wondering if Android people have invented something to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

*This question is quite old but I think it's worth to answer for the benefit os the future readers.*

With GCM (or the new FCM) **there is NO NEED** to keep GCMListenerService in foreground.
Indeed there is no need to keep the app running at all.

When a GCM message is received by the system, your app will be started and the relevant service (GCMListenerService in GCM or FirebaseMessagingService in FCM) will be executed.

The real issue raised by this post is:
*GCM messages are not arriving when the application is not running.*

This is due to a special feature of xiaomi that blocks GCM messages.
see: Autostart whitelist inside the Security section.
http://en.miui.com/thread-117992-1-1.html