# GCM notifications not being recieved when app in foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to setup push notifications to my app containing both data and notification payloads as described in the [official reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). I want both payloads so that I will get an automatic notification when my app is in the background, and the app can handle things itself while in the foreground.

The `onMessageReceived()` method in my `GcmListenerService` is not called when both payloads are included and the app is in the foreground. I have to leave out the notification payload for it to work.

When the app is in the background, it works fine. I get a notification and can open the app when the notification is clicked and do whatever I want from there.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018084/gcm-3-0-notification-payload-not-showing-android-notification-when-app-is-in-for), but they were trying to get a notification when the app is in foreground. I realize I won't get a notification in that case, I just want to get the data.

Relevant portion of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="arkenterprises.garage_o_matic.gcm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MyGcmListenerService.java:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + data);
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String doorStatus = data.getString("DoorStatus");
        String time = data.getString("time");
        Bundle notification = data.getBundle("notification");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        Log.d(TAG, "DoorStatus: " + doorStatus);
        Log.d(TAG, "Time: " + time);
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification: " + notification);
}
```

Server code that sends the message:

```
nowString = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%c")
gcmSendURL = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
gcmHeaders = {'Authorization': 'key=' + API_KEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
gcmDataPayload = {'message': 'Garage door opened', 'DoorStatus': 'Open', 'time': nowString}
gcmNotificationPayload = {'title': 'Garage Door Has Opened', 'body': 'Garage door opened at {}'.format(nowString), 'icon': 'ic_door_open_notification2'}
print('Garage door opened at {}'.format(nowString))
gcmPayload = {'to': regIDs[0].strip(), 'priority': 'high', 'delay_while_idle': False, 'time_to_live': 86400, 'data': gcmDataPayload}
# gcmPayload = {'to': regIDs[0].strip(), 'priority': 'high', 'delay_while_idle': False, 'time_to_live': 86400, 'notification': gcmNotificationPayload}
# gcmPayload = {'to': regIDs[0].strip(), 'priority': 'high', 'delay_while_idle': False, 'time_to_live': 86400, 'content_available': True, 'data': gcmDataPayload, 'notification': gcmNotificationPayload}
print("\nPayload: {}".format(gcmPayload))
r = requests.post(gcmSendURL, headers=gcmHeaders, json=gcmPayload)
print("\nRequest response: " + r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send messages that have both [notification and data payloads](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#components-of-a-message).

I found this [Stack overflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297511/androids-gcmreceiver-gcmlistenerservice-forces-application-to-foreground-on-rec) related to your inquiry, It says that Intent filters will always fire your manifested application as per standard android behavior. Make sure that your logic flow is able to handle the fact that your launch may come from places. Try to implement  ['***GcmMessageHandler***'](https://github.com/AlexMota/ProjetoIntegracao-NotificacoesGoogle/blob/master/Cliente/ClienteNotificacoesGCM/src/com/example/clientenotificacoesgcm/GcmMessageHandler.java) your application must check saved state and sees if user needs to see screen and automatically show notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I had some strange behaviour with samples, but in final I resolved that by removing implementation of GcmListenerService and adding implementation of GcmReceiver.

```
public class MyGcmReceiver extends GcmReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
  }
};
```

and manifest

```
<receiver
   android:name=".MyGcmReceiver"
   android:exported="true"
   android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how to complete this example. I get an error about "Failed to resolve target intent service". It seems like I should have some sort of service set up to replace my GcmListenerService?

Comment: In my case I completely removed  MyGcmListenerService frome code and manifest and it's working fine. But try to build your project with GcmListenerService,  maybe it will clarify something. And please provide more info about errors